# Expo App Crashes on Installation with AssertionError: Manifest Configuration Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

After successfully building my Expo project, the application consistently crashes upon installation. The following error message is displayed:

I've ensured that my android/app/build.gradle file is configured correctly, yet the issue persists. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    
java.lang.AssertionError: The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in android/app/build.gradle. null
```

What I expect

- I expected that the Expo app would be run successfully without any errors.
- Upon installation on my device, I anticipated that the app would run smoothly without any crashes.
- My expectation was for the app to launch without any issues, allowing me to test its functionality on my device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.